# Stop SwiftUI animation from having horizontal movement

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I have an animation that is creating a heartbeat pattern. The issue is that once the text (In the same `HStack`) changes by a reasonable margin the animation oscillates horizontally because it is being pushed by the text. How can I stop this from happening? Is there a way to anchor the Image so that this dramatic horizontal movement does not happen?

```
        HStack(alignment: .bottom){
            Text("\(self.hr)") +  Text("BPM")
            Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                .padding(.init(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 10, trailing: 5))
                .foregroundColor(self.outdatedHR ? Color.gray : Color.red)
                .scaleEffect(self.heart ? 1.05: 0.95, anchor: .center)
                .opacity(self.heart ? 1.0: 0.75)
                .animation(Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever())
                .onAppear{
                    self.heart.toggle()
            }

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give you a perfect answer

```
 .animation( Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(), value: self.heart)
```

That will guarantee the animation restart after the `self.heart` changing

Comment: Very simple and elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of possibilities:

You can put your `Text` in a `VStack` with another `Text` containing what you would consider the longest possible `String` in this context. Even though it is hidden it still forces the `VStack` to take its dimensions. You would need to adjust the spacing in the `VStack` depending on your font size.

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: -20) {
        Text("888 BPM").hidden()
        Text("\(self.hr) BPM")
    }
    Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
    //etc.
}
```

The other option is to give the `Text` an explicit frame width. It is not ideal for dynamic text though:

```
Text("\(self.hr) BPM").frame(width: 100)
```

You could also put a `Spacer()` between the two elements and push the heart all the way to the right.